# Python: Sort print values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here, matrix is a list of lists

This function prints out all the distances between list1 and matrix_a but I am unsure how to get the k lowest distances from matrix_a and the corresponding lists from matrix_b.

I am not allowed to use scikit learn or numpy

```
list1 = [5, 3, 2, 8, 5, 10, 8, 1, 2]
matrix_a = [[1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 7, 2, 1], [4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 8, 1], [3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [5, 4, 6, 6, 4, 10, 4, 3, 1], [5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], [10, 10, 9, 3, 7, 5, 3, 5, 1], [4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1], [5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
matrix_b = [[0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [0]]

def get_distance(list1, list2):
"""returns euclidian distance between 2 lists"""
return sum((p-q)**2 for p, q in zip(list1, list2)) ** .5


def get_k_nearest_labels(list1, matrix_a, matrix_b, k):
    for x in range(len(matrix_a)):
        a = get_distance(list1, matrix_a[x])
        print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store all distances (`a`) in a new list, sort the list and pick the `k` smallest elements.